# class not registered sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, view, ssms

i got this Error while i want Change or create view and change column place

this is photo

[image]

how to fix that

Comment: I think issues is due to improper SQL installation. have you tried repair or re install?

Comment: You can try to repair your install, as maulik says, but my usual recommendation here would be to stop using the view designer. It has bugs. It pretends functionality exists that doesn't (hello, "sorted" view!), doesn't expose functionality that does exist (hello, CTEs), and if you ever get to a point of caring about the layout of your SQL, it doesn't and will mash your code into an unreadable mess at the slightest provocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's Consider the following scenario:

> - You install SQL Server 2012 Management Studio and create a project in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.
> - You install SQL Server 2016 Management Studio on the same computer.

When you try to open the solution (.ssmssln file) or the project (.ssmssqlproj file) using SQL Server Management Studio 2012, you may get the following error:

> “Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))”

**Resolution:**

To workaround this issue, use one of the following methods:

> **Method 1**:  You can use SQL Server Management Studio 2016 on the **same
>   or different system to work** with SQL Server Management Studio 2012
>   projects after the side by side installation.
>
> **Method 2**:  You can **re-install** SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

However it is advised that client tools like SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and 
SQL Server Management Studio 2016 **be installed on separate systems**.